# Are there any rituals or spells that protect a geographical area from magical attacks/scrying etc?

Tags: unknown-armies

I am running a game of Unknown Armies, and my cabal have recently found somewhere they want to set up as a base of operations. I've had a look through the rule book, and can't find any ways of offering general protection from magical attacks/scrying/distance spells. The closest I can see is a ward, but this only works once against a specific individual.

Am I missing something? Is there anything like this in other published splat books?

Answer (score 3):

The ritual section has always been on the sparse side. But there is no reason you couldn't let them research such a ritual themselves. A totem with wards the area, anointing of the entrances of a building with blood and dung from a Hindi sacred cow, or simply a voodoo doll which draws all attacks to it until it's destroyed. As perusal through the [fan site](http://ua.johntynes.com/) should show you, it's not only easy, but in many cases necessary of the storyteller to create homebrew material for the players to use or go up against.